# How to set a fixed item before dynamic items in FlatList of React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have used Flatlist for showing gallary view of few recent images to select.
I have also added a button to invoke a file picker.
But the issue is to show the button as first item of flatlist I used index===0 in render method which causing the skipping of first image from data.

Whell I tried this.
while setting state which contains the data, I simply added extra element

```java
            let data = {
                all:[[],...all],
                anim:[[],...anim],
                still:[[],...still]
            }
```

Now it works. skips the first element of array (means returns the file picker component as item and continue with first image as next item, so first image won't get replaced by file picker)
But it does not look reliable. It won't show folder component until images extracted and set to state. Although I can set this as initial value in state.

But what is the best way to deal with it?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot of react app containing flatlist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best solution here is to pre-define the file picker element as the 0 index of the array and populate the image from the get-go, so it shows immediately and then spread the rest of the data the way that you've done it. There are other stuff that you can try like setting header component, however it will always render above the list, and from the image it seems like your item should be inside the list.

Comment: Thanks. yeah I have used header (All, Animated, Static) )above the items as it always stays above items. If I had to use 3 items

Answer (score 2):

Try ListHeaderComponent as what [Doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent) recommends.

Comment: Header adds component above all the list items  But header is useful if I had full row of component to cover the list columns, so that it would look like list item rather header.